# Как выполнить какое либо действие при нажатии на label?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qt-designer, qlabel

Хочу реализовать при нажатии на `label` изменение текста в другом `label`, но при запуске кода ничего не происходит.

Код:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import QLabel, pyqtSignal

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(708, 520)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 70, 321, 151))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 270, 191, 71))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 708, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        


        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Test label "))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))

class ClickedLabel(QLabel):
    clicked = pyqtSignal()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, e):
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(e)

        self.clicked.emit()

class Testwindow (QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self): 
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.label = ClickedLabel('Label')
        self.label.clicked.connect(self.hi)

    def hi(self):
        self.label_2.setText('Hello')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Testwindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я отметил для вас строки , в которые надо внести изменени

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import QLabel, pyqtSignal

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(708, 520)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 70, 321, 151))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 270, 191, 71))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 708, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Test label "))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))


class ClickedLabel(QLabel):
    clicked = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, text, parent=None):                 # +++
        super(ClickedLabel, self).__init__(parent)         # +++
        self.setText(text)                                 # +++
            
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, e):
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(e)
        self.clicked.emit()


class Testwindow (QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self): 
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.label = ClickedLabel('Label', self)              # + self
        self.label.clicked.connect(self.hi)

    def hi(self):
        self.label_2.setText('Hello')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Testwindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

< а почему зона нажатия расположена в верхнем левом углу? Можно ли её как то переместить?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import QLabel, pyqtSignal

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(708, 520)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 70, 321, 151))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 270, 191, 71))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 708, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Test label "))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))


class ClickedLabel(QLabel):
    clicked = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, text, parent=None):                 # +++
        super(ClickedLabel, self).__init__(parent)         # +++
        self.setText(text)                                 # +++
            
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, e):
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(e)
        self.clicked.emit()


class Testwindow (QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self): 
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.label = ClickedLabel('Label', self)                    # + self
        self.label.setStyleSheet('background: #77f;')               # +++
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 100, 100, 100))    # +++

        self.label.clicked.connect(self.hi)

    def hi(self):
        self.label_2.setText('Hello')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Testwindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а почему зона нажатия расположена в верхнем левом углу? Можно ли её как то переместить?

Comment: @Mswork6 смотрим обновление

Comment: Всё, понял. Спасибо большое!

Comment: @Mswork6 вообще-то абсолютное позиционирование - не практично! Изучите использование `Layout`